# Conference ticketing and seating module for WordPress

Tags: plugin-recommendation, events, paypal

[Previously](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38428) I have asked about free Conferencing modules for WordPress.

Unfortunately, none (free or paid) support seating, i.e.: tickets with seat numbers.

Can you recommend one which does?

Thanks

Comment: Please revise your question with specific needs/functional requirements. Unless we know *exactly* what problem you're trying to solve, this is a guessing game.  See [meta](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/967/are-theme-and-plugin-recommendation-guessing-games) for more discussion ...

Comment: I need tickets with seat numbers.

Comment: Please edit the *question.* Explain exactly the features you need and what solutions you've already looked at that were insufficient.

Comment: Done and done and done

Comment: Nominated for _reopen_

Answer (score 0):

*Late answer - I also added this answer on the other Q as addition to my answer.*

### Possible solution

Your best bet would be to use

1. A Plugin that makes use of Custom Post Types, then use something like the [RW_Meta_Box class library](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box) to add custom fields for seat reservation to the event.
2. Use a DB-option to store all seat numbers (Use the Transients API to clear the entry after the event has expired).
3. Then retrieve the custom field with your seat numbers option during attendee registration and offer only the available seats.